# Output Parameter Value is Not Returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

The store procedure does work fine and it print the values while i'm testing.
But once i want to use the output in the execute command. it returns the prints from the store procedure and 2 blank lines from the execute. i keep on reading the code but it looks fine to me.
Can someone look at this. My store procedure goes as this:

```
if OBJECT_ID ('dbo.usp_OmzetPerFilm')is not null
drop procedure usp_OmzetPerFilm
go 


create procedure usp_OmzetPerFilm
@film varchar(250),
@jaar int,
@jaaromzet float output ,
@TotaalBezoekers int output
as
begin

Select @TotaalBezoekers  = Sum(AantalTickets  ) from ticketVerkoop 
 Inner Join prijsTicket  on prijsTicket .idPrijs  = ticketVerkoop .idPrijs 
 Inner Join film  on film.idfilm   = ticketVerkoop .idfilm 
where @jaar = Jaar and @film = film.naam 

Select @jaarOmzet  = Sum(prijsTicket .prijs  * ticketVerkoop.AantalTickets  ) from ticketVerkoop 
 Inner Join prijsTicket  on prijsTicket .idPrijs  = ticketVerkoop .idPrijs 
  Inner Join film  on film.idfilm   = ticketVerkoop .idfilm 
 where @jaar = Jaar and @film = film.naam 


 --This does work
 print @jaaromzet
 print @totaalBezoekers

end 
go
```

But when i use the execute task. 
It only prints the values form the store procedure but not from the execute command.
Is there something i'm missing ?

```
Declare @TotaleOmzet int
Declare @TotaleBezoekers int
EXECUTE usp_OmzetPerFilm 'hobbit',2014,@TotaleOmzet, @TotaleBezoekers

-- This does not work ?
print @TotaleOmzet
print @TotaleBezoekers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify that the parameter is to be used for OUTPUT:

```
DECLARE @TotaleOmzet FLOAT
DECLARE @TotaleBezoekers INT 
EXECUTE usp_OmzetPerFilm 
    @film = 'hobbit',
    @jaar = 2014,
    @jaaromzet = @TotaleOmzet OUTPUT, 
    @TotaalBezoekers =  @TotaleBezoekers OUTPUT
```

Also, review your types -- you almost certainly want to use `DECIMAL` for financial totals, not `FLOAT`, which can run into accuracy issues.

Comment: I try to use decimal first but when i wanted to store a decimal into a table it rounds up. Do you have a suggestion how to do this ?

Comment: @user3475722: `DECIMAL` accepts both a precision and a scale, so (for example) `DECIMAL(10,5)` can hold a number of 10 digits with 5 digits after the decimal point. `DECIMAL` without anything else is `DECIMAL(18,0)`, which has no fractional part. See [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ibrary/ms187746).

Comment: I will adjust my tables now. i want to give you a +1 but since i'm to low you have my thanks.

Comment: @user3475722: feel free to accept my answer instead, that's good enough. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @TotaleOmzet int
Declare @TotaleBezoekers int
EXECUTE usp_OmzetPerFilm 'hobbit',2014,@TotaleOmzet OUTPUT, @TotaleBezoekers OUTPUT

-- This does not work ?
print @TotaleOmzet
print @TotaleBezoekers
```

You forgot the OUTPUT word when executing the procedure.