# Not returning value on output

Tags: sql, vb.net

****Aim**:** Simply to return a value based on a stored procedure search, this is based on a stored procedure that works with a datagrid but in this instance I only want one value.

****Error**:** Nothing is returned!

**Notes:** Stripped down version

****Code**:**

**.ASPX**

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblLocationsOutput" runat="server" Text="--" CssClass="lblLocationsOutput" />
```

**.ASPX.VB**

```
 Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim command As New SqlCommand
        'Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim ConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mySQL").ToString()
        connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim vLocationNumber As Integer
        connection.Open()
        With command
            .Connection = connection
            .CommandText = "spSearchLocation" 'include audit names
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .Parameters.Clear()
            .Parameters.Add("@LocationsNumber", SqlDbType.Int)
            .Parameters("@LocationsNumber").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sUPRN", sUPRN.Text & " ")                
            .ExecuteNonQuery()


            If .Parameters("@LocationsNumber").Value.ToString = "" Then
                vLocationNumber = "0"
            End If
        End With

        lblLocationsOutput.Text = vLocationNumber
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
USE DATABASE
GO      
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spSearchLocation

@sUPRN varchar(20),
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@LocationsNumber Int OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

--Main SQL
DECLARE @SQLSTRING AS VARCHAR(MAX)


IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@sUPRN)) <> ''  
SET @SQLSTRING = @SQLSTRING + 'or UPRN LIKE ''%''' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(RTRIM(@sUPRN))) + '''%'''


EXECUTE(@SQLSTRING)

END

SET @LocationsNumber = @SQLSTRING
```

Looked at references such as: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528836/output-parameter-value-is-not-returned)

Hopefully a simple error. Does not work even when searching say just a UPRN that I know is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 
   `Select  @LocationsNumber` at the end of the Stored Procedure

Comment: Tried directly after and then before 'END' and after SET LocationsNumber = @SQLSTRING